# ORA-00922 missing or invalid option while trying to create a table for my project

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PROJ_1 Student
(
    StudentID Number (10,0)
    FirstName Varchar2(30),
    LastName Varchar2(30),
    Address Varchar2(50),
    Phone Varchar2(10)
    Email Varchar2(50),
    Associate_Major Varchar2(50),
    Associate_Graduation_Date Date,
    BAS_Status Varchar2(50),
    CatalogYear Varchar2(4),
    Degree_Plan_Developed Varchar2(3),
    BAS_Program_Specialization Varchar2(50),
    AdvvisorID Number(4, 0),
    Comments Varchar2(30),
)
```

Comment: Just remove extra comma before `) `

Comment: Please, try to do a little effort to find which is the error prior to post new questions.

Comment: In addition to the technical issues already identified, I'd point out that, given how oracle handles case-sensitivity (or lack of) in object names, there is no real point in using MixedCaseNames.  Throw away your MickySoft goggles and learn to do things the Oracle way when dealing with Oracle.  Instead of MixedCaseNames for clarity, we use underscore_separated_names.  Instead of FirstName, make it first_name.  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Issues I found:

1. Missing period between `PROJ_1` and `Student`
2. Missing comma before `FirstName`
3. Missing comma before `Email`
4. Extra comma before the last `)`
5. Missing `;` at the end

```
    CREATE TABLE PROJ_1.Student
    (
        StudentID                     NUMBER (10, 0),
        FirstName                     VARCHAR2 (30),
        LastName                      VARCHAR2 (30),
        Address                       VARCHAR2 (50),
        Phone                         VARCHAR2 (10),
        Email                         VARCHAR2 (50),
        Associate_Major               VARCHAR2 (50),
        Associate_Graduation_Date     DATE,
        BAS_Status                    VARCHAR2 (50),
        CatalogYear                   VARCHAR2 (4),
        Degree_Plan_Developed         VARCHAR2 (3),
        BAS_Program_Specialization    VARCHAR2 (50),
        AdvvisorID                    NUMBER (4, 0),
        Comments                      VARCHAR2 (30)
    );
```